# C#: Showing a modal progress dialog during a long process

Tags: c#, multithreading

My software requires to store the directory and registry structure for some particular locations. This usually takes a long time. Let's say I have a method called `SaveState()` which does that.

I want to wrap this into another method, `SaveStateWithProgress()`, so that when I call it, a modal dialog appears, which shows a simple progress bar and has a button to cancel the operation. The way I see it I may need to use two threads, although in VB6 or Java I used to get by with the equivalent of `Thread.Yield()` command - not sure if it is the best practice, and even if there is something similar in C#. What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [site](http://dotnetperls.com/progressbar) that I think would satisfy what you need.

It has example of using a progress bar and background worker (using BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()).

Comment: I upvoted the tutorial in Scott Chamberlain's answer instead of this one because this site doesn't mention the `WorkerReportsProgress` property of the `BackgroundWorker` class, which is absolutely critical and must be set to `True` for progress reporting to work.

Comment: Wasn't the question about showing a prograssbar in a modal window ?

Answer (score 6):

The best method in C# is use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and run your intensive operation inside that background worker.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/) that includes instructions on how to cancel your operation half way.

Answer (score -1):

In C#, you can call `Thread.Sleep(0)` or `Thread.Sleep(1)` to do the same thing as Java's `Thread.Yield()`.

With that said, you will definately need to do your `SaveState()` in a separate thread. Have a variable in your `SaveState()` function that gets updated as `SaveState()` progresses. Put a timer control in your modal progress form and have the timer check this variable that `SaveState()` is updating. Update your progress bar appropriately

Comment: It's true that `Thread.Sleep(0)` will yield the current thread, but that does you no good if your UI is running on the same thread.  The .NET Framework does have `Application.DoEvents()` to essentially yield to one pass of the message pump loop, but using a `BackgroundWorker` is much to be preferred.

Answer (score -2):

```
ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
p.Location = new Point(10, 10);
p.Size = new Size(100, 30);
p.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
p.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```